# How can i set timeout for SQLQuery?

Tags: java, querydsl

Method creating SQLQuery using querydsl-sql :

```
 protected final <T> T select(RelationalPathBase path, Function<SQLQuery, T> code) throws SQLException {
    try (final Connection con = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        return code.apply(new SQLQuery(con, SQLServer2008Templates.builder().printSchema().build()).from(getTable(path)));
    }
}
```

Method using query:

```
public List<Tuple> selectDataForProcess() throws SQLException {
    return select(map, sqlQuery -> sqlQuery
            .limit(sendSelectBatch)
            .where(map.selectedOn.isNull())
            .list(map.all()));

}
```

How can i set timeout for query ?

Comment: You could launch your query as a thread with another paralel thread that interrupts the execution when a timer has reached your selected time.

Comment: Are you using Spring?

Comment: Yes, but is it important ?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to know where your datasource came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was in using old version of query-sql.
In latest releases timeout can be set like this:

```
  SQLQuery<Tuple> select = queryFactory.select(map.all());
    select.setStatementOptions(StatementOptions.builder().setQueryTimeout(queryTimeout).build());
```

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, I believe `datasource` is spring managed. Either set the default timeout on the datasource level:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <!-- Sets default timeout to 5 seconds -->
    <property name="defaultTimeout" value="5" />
</bean>
```

Or wrap an individual query in a transaction and set the timeout:

```
@Transactional(timeout=5)
```

Comment: But if i needn't transactional behavior ? Querytimeout can be set on PreparedStatement.  Every time when i call .list() querydsl creates PreparedStatement for execute, but i cant see way to specify such usual parameters (timeout, maxrows etc)